# Netbeans 8.2 installing native library error

Tags: java, windows, netbeans

On my Windows 10 (x64) Laptop, I installed JDK8.151 (x64) and added the jre bin and jdk bin paths to the system variables under PATH in enviroment variables. However when I installed the Netbeans 8.2 (x64) (JavaSE) version from Netbeans' website and ran it, an error appeared: Cannot load native library from path:native/jnilib/windows/windows-x64.dll

Comment: I don't think so this is your JDK or PATH issue. Looks like more on Netbeans. Run run installer with "--verbose --output out.txt"  and post the output.txt in the NetBeans forum.

Comment: Thank you. How do I run the installer with verbose output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run [no need to be as `admin`] `cmd`.

```
C:\Users\pc>echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

if you don't get such a clause:

> ```
> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin
> ```

Go to your environment variables and for both `user` and `system` variables

> ```
> set JAVA_HOME -> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin
> ```