# Netbeans IDE Users - Problems Installing Netbeans 8.0.2 on Windows 10

Tags: java, windows, netbeans

On my Windows 10 (x64) Laptop
I installed JDK8.151 (x64) and added the jre bin and jdk bin paths to the system variables under PATH in enviroment variables.
However when I installed the Netbeans 8.2 (x64) (JavaSE) version from Netbeans website and ran it, Following error appeared:

> Cannot load native library from
>   path:native/jnilib/windows/windows-x64.dll

Comment: Use the installer, not the zip file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Netbeans 8.2 installing native library error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47042091/2985643)